# Summation of array based on mask with different values

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, python-xarray

To make the question easy to understand I make some plots step by step below.

1. 3D array called `data` which is the data I want to get the summation based on `feature` and `mask`.

   [image: data]
2. 3D array called `mask` (same shape as `data`) which is used to subset `data`.

   Colors show the relationship between `data`, `feature` and `mask`. I will explain it below.

   [image: mask]
3. I have a one dimension DataArray called `feature` whose values are part of `mask`.

   All values of `feature` are not duplicated, but the `time` dimension has some duplicated values.

   [image: feature]

Steps:

- loop the `feature` by the `time` coordinate
- Create a temporary mask based on `mask` and looped `feature`:

  `1` for both time and value equal to the chosen feature; `0` for others
- Use the temporary mask to mask `data`, sum the masked data, and save it to new data called `data_mask` which has the same shape of `feature`.

Here's the result:

[image: result]

I have written the code using for loop:

```
import xarray as xr
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# create feature example
t_feature = pd.to_datetime(['2019-07-25 00:00', '2019-07-25 00:00', '2019-07-25 01:00'])
feature = xr.DataArray(np.array([1,2,4]),
                       coords=[t_feature],
                       dims={'time': t_feature})

# create mask example
t = pd.to_datetime(['2019-07-25 00:00', '2019-07-25 01:00'])
mask_t1 = np.array([[1,1,1], [2,2,2], [3,3,3]])
mask_t2 = mask_t1*2
mask = np.stack((mask_t1, mask_t2))
mask = xr.DataArray(mask, coords=[t, range(3), range(3)], dims=['time', 'x', 'y'])

# create data example
data = np.ones(mask.shape)
data[0, 1, :] *= 2
data[1, ...] *= 3
data = xr.DataArray(data, coords=[t, range(3), range(3)], dims=['time', 'x', 'y'])

data_mask = feature.copy()

for index,f in enumerate(feature):
    timestamp = f.time
    pair_mask = mask.sel(time=timestamp)
    pair_mask = pair_mask.where(pair_mask==f, False)

    data_mask[dict(time=index)] = data.sel(time=timestamp).where(pair_mask).sum()
```

But, it is too slow for a large Dataset. If you have any better advice, I would appreciate a lot!

### Update

According to Oxbowerce's suggestions, I figured out three methods and test the speed.

#### Conclusion

The speed of `xarray` method is quickest, but it can cause memory error.

`pandas` method can cause memory error too and is slower than `xarray` method.

`for loop` is slowest but doesn't have memory problem as the data has been loaded.

#### Details

```
import xarray as xr
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

len_t = int(1e3)
# create feature example
t = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', periods=len_t, freq='S')
feature = xr.DataArray(np.random.randint(len_t/2, size=len_t),
#                        range(len_t),
                       coords=[t],
                       dims={'time': t})

# create mask example
mask = xr.DataArray(np.random.randint(len_t/2, size=(len_t, 50, 50)),  coords=[t, range(50), range(50)], dims=['time', 'x', 'y'])

# create data example
data = mask.copy()
data_mask = feature.copy()

# --- method 1: for loop --- #
for index,f in enumerate(feature):
    timestamp = f.time
    pair_mask = mask.sel(time=timestamp)
    pair_mask = pair_mask.where(pair_mask==f, False)

    data_mask[dict(time=index)] = data.sel(time=timestamp).where(pair_mask).sum()

# --- method 2: pandas --- #
# convert xarrays to pandas dataframes
data_df = data.to_dataframe(name="data_value").reset_index()
feature_df = feature.to_dataframe(name="feature_value")
mask_df = mask.to_dataframe(name="mask_value").reset_index()


result = (
    data_df
    # add mask values data
    .merge(mask_df, how="left", on=["time", "x", "y"])
    # add feature values to data, using inner join to only leave rows present in feature array
    .merge(feature_df, how="inner", left_on=["time", "mask_value"], right_on=["time", "feature_value"])
    # group rows and add up the values
    .groupby("feature_value")
    .sum()["data_value"]
)

# --- method 3: xarray --- #
feature_time = feature.time
merge_ds = xr.merge([data.rename('data'), mask.rename('mask')], join="left").sel(time=feature_time)
result = merge_ds['data'].where(merge_ds['mask']==feature, drop=True).sum(dim=['x', 'y'])
```

Here's executed time:

- for loop: `5.24 s ± 30.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`
- pandas method: `1.48 s ± 27.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`
- xarray method: `74.3 ms ± 2.03 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the example you've given, I first convert all xarrays to pandas dataframe and use joins to combine the data. I filter on rows where the value in the mask array is present in the feature array and add up the values. This looks like this:

```
import xarray as xr
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# create feature example
t_feature = pd.to_datetime(['2019-07-25 00:00', '2019-07-25 00:00', '2019-07-25 01:00'])
feature = xr.DataArray(np.array([1,2,4]),
                       coords=[t_feature],
                       dims={'time': t_feature})

# create mask example
t = pd.to_datetime(['2019-07-25 00:00', '2019-07-25 01:00'])
mask_t1 = np.array([[1,1,1], [2,2,2], [3,3,3]])
mask_t2 = mask_t1*2
mask = np.stack((mask_t1, mask_t2))
mask = xr.DataArray(mask, coords=[t, range(3), range(3)], dims=['time', 'x', 'y'])
print(mask)
# create data example
data = np.ones(mask.shape)
data[0, 1, :] *= 2
data[1, ...] *= 3
data = xr.DataArray(data, coords=[t, range(3), range(3)], dims=['time', 'x', 'y'])

# convert xarrays to pandas dataframes
data_df = data.to_dataframe(name="data_value").reset_index()
feature_df = feature.to_dataframe(name="feature_value")
mask_df = mask.to_dataframe(name="mask_value").reset_index()

result = (
    data_df
    # add mask values data
    .merge(mask_df, how="left", on=["time", "x", "y"])
    # add feature values to data, using inner join to only leave rows present in feature array
    .merge(feature_df, how="inner", left_on=["time", "mask_value"], right_on=["time", "feature_value"])
    # group rows and add up the values
    .groupby("feature_value")
    .sum()["data_value"]
)
```

Which gives the following result:

| feature_value | data_value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 6 |
| 4 | 9 |

Comment: It looks simpler in pandas. But, the execution time is much longer than the for loop method of xarray. The data shape is (138,801,1101) and `reset_index` converts it into (121702338), it's slow to merge this kind of large Dataframe.

Comment: It seems you can also perform joins/merges with xarrays, see [this link](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.merge.html). Have you tried doing it this way?

Comment: `xarray.merge` doesn't have `left_on` and `right_on` method. I will try again tomorrow ;) Thanks for the advice!

Comment: I figure out the solution using xarray only.

```
feature_time = feature.time
merge_ds = xr.merge([data.rename('data'), mask.rename('mask')], join="left").sel(time=feature_time)
merge_ds['data'].where(merge_ds['mask']==feature, drop=True).sum(dim=['x', 'y'])
```

You can update your answer now :)

Comment: Note that the pandas and xarray method are both slower than the direct for loop ...

Comment: Can you provide timings for all three methods and a larger example that is more in line with the array sizes you are working with?

Comment: Added the new tests.

Comment: Using xarrays seems quite a lot faster to me (`74ms` vs `5.2s`), does that method not work for you?

Comment: It works for me. But, it could cause memory error when the data is large because it doubles the dataset. Anyway, the xarray is the first option if the memory is large enough :)